# wait for Kendo charts to be fully drawn

Tags: javascript, c#, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have many Kendo charts drawn to a page (each chart is a partial view). When they are all fully rendered I need to then create images from them and write the image-data to a database. Although all the charts are written to the database some of them don't have data, just the axes and legend, etc.

Initially, I was using `onRender` to `getKendoChart` but understand now that this means *ready to render*. Instead I am just using `onRender` to collect the id's for the charts.

```
function onRender(e) {      // "Fired when the chart is ready to render on screen."
    var elementId = e.sender.element[0].id;
    // e.g. chartTargetPrice43
    var id = elementId.substring("chartTargetPrice".length); // 43

    renderedCharts.push({ id: id }); //, chart: $('#' + elementId).getKendoChart() });

    renderedTotal += 1;
}
```

I then poll with a 2 second interval to wait until all the id's are collected. Then I will collect the image data for all charts and use `exportImage` to save them to the database. The full function is below for reference.

How can I check that a chart has been fully rendered without having to introduce arbitrary delays with `setTimeout`s?

```
function exportRenderedCompany(idArray) {
    // idArray is an array, but could just have one element

    var countRequests = idArray.length;

    while (idArray.length > 0) {
        var id = idArray.shift();

        // renderedCharts.find(x => x.id == id)... IE11 does not recognise 'find', so
        var foundChart;

        for (var i = 0; i < renderedCharts.length; i++) {
            if (renderedCharts[i].id == id) {
                //foundChart = renderedCharts[i].chart;
                foundChart = $('#chartTargetPrice' + id).getKendoChart();
                break;
            }
        }

        foundChart.exportImage({ width: 694, height: 250 }).done(function (data) {

            // split 'image/png,xxxyyy=' into two
            var dataParts = data.split(',', 2);
            // TODO: need to strip from 'data:image/png;base64'
            dataParts[0] = 'image/png';

            $.ajax({
                url: "@Url.Action("Export_TargetPrice", "Charts")",
                type: 'POST',
                data: { contentType : dataParts[0], base64 : dataParts[1], companyID: id }
            }).done(function () {
                countRequests--;
                if (countRequests <= 0) {
                    window.location.href = "@Url.Action("Recommendations","Charts", new { page = page + 1 })#autoOnRender";
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no event that tells you, that your client is acutally finished rendering, but the last accessible event in the lifecycle of the grid is the dataBound event.

Comment: Thank you. I think I could then try using `dataBound` for each chart, wait 5 secs (an arbitrary figure) for the chart to complete drawing, push its id and data (`getKendoChart`) into my collection. When all the id's are available, export them all. This must be better than calling `getKendoChart` for all of them in a loop, do you think?

Comment: Actually, looking at the [telerik docs](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/chart-api/events) and example, Render occurs after DataBound.

Comment: The mvc controls is just a wrapper around kendo ui and that has no Fender event, so I'm not really sure what is happening there.